# editing or updating the property details of a jpg file in java

Tags: java, file-properties

I am trying to update the property details of a jpg file on runtime in java, like **Copyright, title , subject , author etc.**

Is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: This library will help https://drewnoakes.com/code/exif/

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this:

**The Easy Way**

Use a library which can perform the task for you. Few lines of code.

For example:

https://drewnoakes.com/code/exif/

**The Hard Way**

Learn about the [JPEG file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG) and do it manually.

Comment: Hi , Thanks for reply, I have tried it,yes i am able to print the details, metadeta in to the output, but what i need is i want to update some field in meta data, and i am unable to file some example or help regarding it.

If you have any source or example for it, it would be a great help..
Thanks